# "Через не могу" — нужны ли кавычки для этого выражения?

Tags: кавычки, словосочетания

Какой вариант будет верным?

1. *Я продолжил разговор почти **через не могу**.*
2. *Я продолжил разговор почти **через "не могу"**.*
3. *Я продолжил разговор почти **"через не могу"**.*

Примеры из Нацкорпуса не помогли разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Я продолжил разговор почти через не могу.**
[Орфографический словарь](https://orfo.ruslang.ru/abc/part/che?start=171602&end=171902) фиксирует написание без кавычек.
Это словосочетание (как и подобное ему *"через не хочу"*) рассматривается как одно наречие.